# Create WPF page fragment in Visual Studio 2015 (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, avalondock, docking

I am trying to develop multi-document interface for C# application (that is suprisingly hard, in Delphi it was and still is the simple task for more than two decades!!!) and it seems to me that I should use AvalonDoc framework for this https://avalondock.codeplex.com/

The essence is - all the dynamic documents will be the parts (fragments) of one (main) C# Window and there will be one XAML file - that is require by Avalon.

My intention is to create separate XAML and code-behind file for each document, **is it possible to create fragments in Visual Studio 2015? E.g. such code pieces that does not inherit from Window and that can be dynamically inserted into window** (e.g. as AvalonDock LayoutDocument's).

I know that VS has notion of controls and components but I am not sure - is it right practice to create entire documents (e.g. invoices, stores) as single components/controls?

Comment: Actually I don't need Docking specifically. MDI is fine for me. But from several sources I have found that WPF does not support MDI. However I see in 'Add New Item...', that there is option to create new Parent Window. So, maybe it is possible to create MDI in WPF? That could be the solution for my initial problem.

Comment: OK, I understand. Parent Window if for Windows Forms framework and there is no similar option for WPF. So sad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create `UserControls` -

They belong to the list of standard template files in Visual Studio.

A `UserControl` is :

1 A Xaml file for describing content. 
You can design it graphically or with code editing.

2 C# or Vb.net file for codebehind = event handlers, data members, extra methods , ...

Both files make a single class during compilation thanks to the partial keyword.

Once the Usercontrol is compiled you can drag and drop it onto the surface of a Window like a standard control (e.g. button).

Usercontrols can also be instanciated through C#/Vb.Net code.

Let me know if I answer correctly - if I am complettely wrong - I Delete, or I complete if needed